# Can I create user shortcut in active directory

Tags: user-accounts, windows-server-2003, active-directory

In fact I want to create shortcut for existing user for example I have two OUs name 1 and 2 inside OU 1 there is user1 and I want create shortcut for user1 inside OU 2? another meaning I want user1 to be member in OU 1 and 2.

Comment: You might consider telling us what the larger problem is you are trying to solve?  We may have other ideas.

Comment: OK I have filez service installed on Linux server and and it's connected to active directory via ldap about active directory I have OU which contain all the users. I won't all the users using filez so I have to create another OU and some users will member in the both OUs. I hope I explained well. Thanks for your help

Comment: AD OUs is not the best way to structure such a permission for this exact reason.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe AD works that way.  As far as I know, an object can only be a member of one OU.

If you're trying to apply group policies, it would make sense to create a security group and have the policy applied to all members of the group.

Comment: AD does not allow for aliases (aka shorcuts).

Comment: A security group is the best bet, especially if you it involves permission to resources like printers or directories.